# Did I choose the correct equation to calculate this?

Tags: python, math

I'm not sure if there is actually an error here, but I (out of curiosity) created a program that calculated how many people across ~241 generations had... let's say *intimate relations* before just one person in Generation Z was born, and then following that how many people had *intimate relations* before the whole population of Generation Z was born.

Prerequisites: There are 72.1 million people in Gen Z, and one Generation lasts 25 years. All relationships are monogamous. Each couple has one child.

```
import time

#I made this program out of pure curiousity (I'm not lewd, I promise) and I found it pretty interesting.

#Bunny art

print("      z")
print("    z")
print("   z")
print("(\(\ ")
print("(– -)")
print("(‘)(’)")

#Variable Declarations

generationLength = 25
totalYears = 6026
numberOfGenerations = totalYears / generationLength
numberOfCalculations = 0
numberOfPeople = 1
numberOfPeopleOnEarth = 7750000000
numberOfPeopleInThisGeneration = 72100000

def howManyPeopleHadSexBeforeICameIntoExistence():
  
  #Mathematics
  numberOfCalculations = 0
  while (numberOfCalculations < numberOfGenerations):
    numberOfPeople = numberOfGenerations * 2
    numberOfCalculations = numberOfCalculations + 1

  #Output
  time.sleep(2)
  print("\nCalculating pointless knowledge...")
  time.sleep(2)
  print("At least " + str(round(numberOfPeople)) + " people in had sex before one person in Generation Z was born.")
  
  #Mathematics
  total = round(numberOfPeople * numberOfPeopleInThisGeneration)

  #Output
  time.sleep(2)
  print("\nCalculating extra trivia...")
  time.sleep(2)
  print("At least " + str(total) + " had sex before every person in Generation Z was born.")



howManyPeopleHadSexBeforeICameIntoExistence()
```

Comment: I would suggest you make a simple example where you start with one couple and go 3 generations down. Do the problem with paper and pen (no programming), calculate manually the results on each generation and the accumulated results at the last generation. Once you have your problem done and verified on paper make a simple code that prints the results for each generation and at the end. Debug your program if it doesn't give you the same results and understand why. Then just change the number of generations from 3 to whatever number you want

Comment: When I was originally writing the program, I was only calculating it based on the last ~81 generations (over 2022 years) and I guess I forgot to update it to ~241 (over 6026 years). Though after updating the program to 2026 years, it doesn't change the output. I double them because it takes two people to procreate, so one person has two parents, each of the parents have two parents, and so on. As far as the number of children per couple, that was outside of the scope of what I wanted to do, so I should have added "Only one child per couple" to the prerequisites. How would you have done it?

Comment: if each couple has only one child, your population will be reduced by half at each generation leading to inevitable extinction.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time

# I made this program out of pure curiousity (I'm lewd, I promise) and I found it pretty interesting.

# Bunny art

print("      z")
print("    z")
print("   z")
print("(\(\ ")
print("(– -)")
print("(‘)(’)")



# Variable Declarations

generationLength = 25
totalYears = 6026
numberOfGenerations = totalYears / generationLength
numberOfPeopleOnEarth = 7750000000
numberOfPeopleInThisGeneration = 72100000
percentage_of_current_generation = numberOfPeopleInThisGeneration/numberOfPeopleOnEarth
max_age = 100

def howManyPeopleHadSexBeforeICameIntoExistence():
    numberOfPeople = numberOfPeopleInThisGeneration * (2 ** numberOfGenerations) - numberOfPeopleInThisGeneration
    # Output
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\nCalculating pointless knowledge...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("At least " + str(round(numberOfPeople)) + " people in history had sex before one person in Generation Z was born.")

    # Mathematics
    total_alive = round(numberOfPeopleInThisGeneration * (2 ** (max_age/generationLength)) - 1)

    # Output
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\nCalculating extra trivia...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("At least " + str(total_alive) + " people currently alive had sex before every person in Generation Z was born.")


howManyPeopleHadSexBeforeICameIntoExistence()
```